# How to detect non-roman characters in JS?

Tags: javascript, localization

How can I detect non-roman characters in a string? Mind you, it's not as simple as classing all characters outside of the scope A-Z and 0-9. There are lots of variations on roman characters like the German ä,ö,ü - which are still roman, "中文" on the other hand, is clearly not roman script.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. We give help to specific problems, and it is common for the asker to present what he tried so far to solve his problem him/herself and get feedback and help based on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript is natively Unicode and the character ranges for various scripts are well documented at http://www.unicode.org/charts/

You will see that there are several blocks that correspond to Latin (Roman) scripts. The most common of these is the high ASCII range known as Latin-1 supplement in the range 0080–00FF. This will include the German characters you mention.

JavaScript lets us test for Unicode ranges nicely using Regular expressions. So you could detect Latin 1 supplement characters in several strings as per this example:

```
var en = 'Coffee',
    fr = 'Café',
    el = 'Καφές';

console.log( en.replace( /[\u0080-\u00FF]/g, '*') );
console.log( fr.replace( /[\u0080-\u00FF]/g, '*') );
console.log( el.replace( /[\u0080-\u00FF]/g, '*') );
```

This will print out:

```
Coffee
Caf*
Καφές
```

Because according to our character ranges only the accented `é` matches the latin supplement range (hence it is replaced with `*`)

So to better answer your question, to detect "non-roman" characters you could do:

```
var str = 'a ä ö ü 中 文',
    reg = /[^\u0000-\u024F\u1E00-\u1EFF\u2C60-\u2C7F\uA720-\uA7FF]/g;

console.log( str.replace( reg, '?') );
```

Which would show:

```
a ä ö ü ? ?
```

You can use these ranges to do whatever it is you specifically need. I put together [this crude tool](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/js/regex) for building regex from unicode blocks, but I'm quite sure there are better resources out there,